# How do I Start My Browser (Firefox) the Way Selenium Does?

Tags: firefox, selenium

I've got a Selenium test which crashes my browser (Firefox) whenever it runs.  It's just a simple test (login, logout, login, logout, login ... crash) and I can't reproduce the crash when I do the same things manually, so I *think* the problem is with Selenium itself.

However, the issue could be that my Firefox starts with different options than when Selenium starts it.  I could confirm that's not the case if I could start Firefox the exact same way Selenium starts it (eg. without plug-ins, with all history cleared, etc.) ... but I'm not sure how to do that.

Can anyone tell me which options to use to make Firefox run the same way as when Selenium runs it?

Comment: Could you not create a very basic class that starts your Webdriver browser but does no action allowing you to then perform your manual actions in that Webdriver browser?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but it doesn't really help, as I'm trying to determine whether this issue is being caused by Selenium driver itself.  If I manually test in Firefox without Selenium and the browser crashes I know my problem isn't Selenium, but if I manually test via a blank Selenium test I don't really learn anything I didn't already know.

Comment: Unless told otherwise, by your code, Selenium will start Firefox with a clean new profile. Have you tried stepping through your code?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately when I try Firefox with a clean new profile the bug doesn't manifest (I can log out/in three, or even six times, without issue).  As for stepping through, yes I've tried that, but it always fails at the same spot (when I try to login the 3rd time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to find out how to emulate Selenium's use of Firefox.  I tried using a fresh Firefox profile, but that still seemed to have differences from how Selenium ran Firefox.

Instead I wound up re-writing my test to be two tests, and then it was able to log in/out twice in the first test and once in the second test, avoiding the issue I was trying to debug (which only manifests when I try to log in/out 3 times in the same test).

If anyone can provide a better explanation of how to emulate Selenium's running of Firefox I'd be happy to accept that answer.